# Как преобразовать строку char в строку unsigned char в языке С?

Tags: c, массивы, строки, типы-данных, символы

Язык C
Считываю строку из консоли:

```
char a[256]=0;   
fgets(a, 256, stdin);
```

Но потом строку b надо использовать в качестве аргумента функции:

```
int function (unsigned char a[]) {  
...  
}
```

Как переделать строку, чтобы её можно было использовать в качестве аргумента?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы точно компилируете в режиме С - то ничего делать не надо. Все преобразования выполняются неявно:

```
int function (unsigned char a[]) {  
}  

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    char a[256] = { 0 };
    fgets(a, 256, stdin);

    function(a);
}
```

Вот этот код, компилируемый GCC без замечаний: https://ideone.com/tbwNRz
У меня его скомпилировал VC++2017

А вот если вы, несмотря на тэг `C`, компилируете его как С++ - то нужно явное приведение типа, например,

```
function((unsigned char*)(a));
```

Comment: Уверены, что это разрешено в С? GCC с `-pedantic-errors` [не компилирует](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9cd4ac81ba21ee6e).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Я тут недавно уже писал, что я человек "более наук практических", и всегда с интересом выслушаю гуру, которые со стандартом в руках обоснуют, что компиляторы не должны что-то компилировать...

Comment: @Harry, да, строго говоря, стандарт требует явного приведения указателей на все *несовместимые типы* (*несовместимые* — это красивое слово, чтобы сказать просто *различные*), кроме случая когда одним из них является `void *`... а с точки зрения стандарта `char`, `signed char` и `unsigned char` — три разные типа...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, если что, дисклеймер в доках gcc явно предупреждает, что не стоит ожидать, что `-pedantic` — это необходимое или достаточное условие для проверки строгому соответствию стандарту...

Comment: @Fat-Zer Это понятно, но все-таки ошибается GCC довольно редко, особенно в сишном коде.